# ¿Cómo se levantan varios proyectos con Docker?

Tags: docker

Tengo un sistema en `Angular` y `ionic` donde se manejan 3 vistas o proyectos individuales que son: vista Cliente, Negocio y Administrador. Tengo su backend en `MySQL` que usa `Nestjs`.

Estoy aprendiendo docker y quisiera crear un contenedor que levante esos 3 proyectos más el backend, así ahorrarme el tener varias consolas abiertas.

No tengo muy claro como crear las reglas para unificar todo esto y se levanten en conjunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas, puedes utilizar Docker Compose para definir y orquestar los contenedores de tus tres proyectos individuales (Cliente, Negocio y Administrador) junto con el backend basado en Nest.js y MySQL. Docker Compose te permitirá administrar múltiples contenedores como una aplicación única. Aquí hay un resumen de los pasos que debes seguir:

Estructura del proyecto

```html
proyecto-principal/
├── cliente/
│   ├── ... (código del proyecto Cliente)
├── negocio/
│   ├── ... (código del proyecto Negocio)
├── administrador/
│   ├── ... (código del proyecto Administrador)
├── backend/
│   ├── ... (código del backend Nest.js)
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  cliente:
    build:
      context: ./cliente
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
  negocio:
    build:
      context: ./negocio
    ports:
      - "4300:4300"
  administrador:
    build:
      context: ./administrador
    ports:
      - "4400:4400"
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: yourpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: yourdatabase
```

Archivos Dockerfile:
En cada uno de los directorios cliente, negocio, administrador, y backend, crea un archivo Dockerfile para construir las imágenes Docker correspondientes. Aquí hay un ejemplo de un Dockerfile para una aplicación Angular (puedes ajustar esto según las necesidades de tus proyectos):

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:14

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the app will run on
EXPOSE 4200

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Construcción y ejecución:
Abre una terminal en la raíz de tu proyecto principal y ejecuta los siguientes comandos:

Para construir las imágenes de Docker:

```
docker-compose build
```

Para iniciar los contenedores

```
docker-compose up
```

Acceso a tus aplicaciones:
Puedes acceder a tus aplicaciones a través de los puertos que especificaste en el archivo docker-compose.yml. Por ejemplo, si el Cliente está en el puerto 4200, puedes acceder a él en tu navegador utilizando http://localhost:4200.